# XSLT: deep-equal without order/sequence

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

We are having 3 different programs/medium wherein the same kind of XML is getting generated which varies in values and ordering of element.

I am supposed to pick particular element from those XML and need to check whether each child/element/attributes are matching or not. I had used a deep-equal function and it's giving me proper output also but that is not 100% assured. Because sometimes the ordering of nodes may vary which is allowed and as well as attributes too(in order only).

Does anyone know how to compare two nodes the way deep-equal method do without worrying about the sequence/order?

Please let me know if further information is required in order to provide answer.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the sequence of elements is meaningful in XML, so functions like deep-equal are sequence-sensitive.  There is no built-in sequence-insensitive equivalent; that's a particular idiom adopted in some vocabularies, but it's enough of a special case that functions to support it don't belong in a general library.

To solve your immediate problem:  for elements where the order of the children does not matter, normalize the order (e.g. sort somehow in a deterministic way) and then use deep-equal.

Comment: True. Sorting on node element and node attributes could be a solution and moving towards it.

Appreciated your effort and answer.